# what's *p when p is declared as int (*)[size] and assigned to an array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, dereference

code:

```
int arr[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
int (*p)[5] = &arr;
printf("p:%p\n",p);
printf("*p:%p\n",*p);
```

result: `p = *p = arr = 0x7ffee517c830` they are all the address of the array
[image]

The right way to use `p` to visit arr[i] is `*(*p+i)`

The type of pointer `p` is `int(*)[5]`, so p point to an array which type is `int [5]`. But we can't say that p point to an invisible shell of `arr`, p is a variable after all. It stores the address of `arr`, which is also the address of `arr[0]`, the first element of `arr`.

I thought `*p` will get me `1`, which is the first element of `arr`.

The dereference operation means take the value in `p` as address and get the value from this address. Right?
So p stores the address of `arr`，which is `0x7ffee517c830` here, and `1` is stored in this address. Isn't `**p` illegal? The first dereference give us `1`, and second dereference will use `1` as address which is illegal.

What I am missing?

Comment: It's simpler to just say: `int* p = arr;`

Comment: @selbie well, those do different things. There are some use cases for `int (*p)[5]`

Answer (score 5):

The result of `*p` is an lvalue expression of array type.  Using `(*p)` is *exactly the same* as using `arr` in any expression you could now think of.

For example:

- `&*p` means `&arr`
- `**p` means `*arr` (which is legal).
- `(*p)[i]` means `arr[i]`.
- `sizeof *p` means `sizeof arr`.

Arrays are not special in this regard. You can see the same phenomenon with `int x; int *q = &x;`. Now `*q` and `x` have exactly the same meaning.

---

Regarding your last paragraph, I think you are confusing yourself by imagining pointers as glorified integers. Some people teach pointers this way but IMO it is not a good teaching technique because it causes the exact confusing you are now having.

If you dereference an `int(*)[5]` you get an `int[5]` and that's all there is to it. The data type matters in dereferencing. It does not make sense to talk about "dereferencing `0x7ffee517c830`".  Again this is not peculiar to arrays;  if you dereference a `char ***`, you get a `char **` etc.

The only way in which arrays are "different" in this discussion is what happens if you try to do arithmetic on them, or output them, etc. If you supply an `int[5]` as a printf argument for example, there is implicit conversion to `int *` pointing at the first of those 5 ints. This conversion also happens when applying the `*` operator to an `int[5]`, which is why you get an `int` out of that.

Comment: `char***` is surely pointing to somewhere else than `char**` as the latter cannot point to itself, which IMO the OP may object.

Comment: @iBug that's not really a substantial difference . But either way OP needs to understand the implicit conversion of array to pointer ("decay rule") which I describe in the last paragraph

Comment: Your view is like how we translate `101110101....01` . `int` and `float` will get the different result. But first we need to know the binary numbers then we could talk about how to use them. A variable have two means ,the address (lvalue) and the value in that address(rvalue), but they are using the same symbol.Compiler will decide which it means. X(lvalue)=Y(rvalue) . Agree?
 And you mean `*p` gets the lvalue expression of array type, because it's type is `int [5]`?  So why `*pi` gets the rvalue if pi point to `int`，and `*pi` type is `int`.

Comment: I just want to know what binary numbers `*p` get and why is that

Comment: @MMMMMCCLXXVII You are using the terms "lvalue" and "rvalue" completely incorrectly.   The object representation of an array is the representation of its elements concatenated (E.g. `1011010010111010` could be the repesentation of either `short` or `char[2]`).  `*p` *is* an lvalue, it's not an address. There's no such thing as "get the lvalue" or "get the rvalue" or "get binary numbers". `*pi` is also an lvalue. The result of `*` is always an lvalue.

Comment: Before you ask any more questions about `*p`,  try substituting `arr` into your question instead of `*p`.  If you understand that then you have answered your own question.

Answer (score 2):

`p` is declared as a 'pointer to int[5]'.

`arr` is declared as an 'int[5]`

so the initializer `p = &arr;` is not really that strange.  If you substituted any primitive type for `int[5]` you wouldn't bat an eye.

`*p` is another handle on arr. so (*p)[0] = 1.

This really only comes up in wierd cases.  It's most natural where you dereference the pointer-to-array using the subscript operator.  Here's a contrived example where I want to pass a table as argument.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int print_row_range(int (*tab) [2], int first, int last)
{
  int i;
  for(i=first; i<= last; i++)
  {
    printf("{%d, %d}\n", tab[i][0], tab[i][1]);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int arr[3][2] = {{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};
  print_row_range(arr,1,2);
}
```

This example treats the table as an array of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Dereferencing doesn't give you a **value**. It gives you an **object**, which can be used as a value of its type if it can be converted to.

`*p`, being identical to `arr`, is an **object** of an array of 5 ints, so if you want to get an integer from the array, **you must dereference it again** like `(*p)[3]`.

Consider a bigger example:

```
int arr[5][5];
int (*p)[5] = arr;
```

Now you get `arr[0]` with `*p`, which itself is an array of 5. Here comes the difference:

```
*( p+1) == arr[1];
*(*p+1) == arr[0][1];
  ^              ^^^
```

Got the point?

Answer (score 0):

One use case is to be able to allocate with malloc an 2D (or more) pointer of arrays with only one malloc:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static int (*foo(size_t n))[42] {
  return malloc(sizeof *foo(0) * n);
  // return malloc(sizeof(int [n][42]); works too
}

int main(void) {
  size_t n = 42;
  int (*p)[42] = foo(n);
  if (!p) {
    return 1;
  }

  printf("p:");
  int accu = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < sizeof *p / sizeof **p; j++) {
      p[i][j] = accu++;
      printf(" %d", p[i][j]);
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
  free(p);
}
```

I think this very funny.

One more with VLA:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void *foo(size_t elem, size_t n, size_t m) {
  return malloc(elem * n * m);
}

int main(void) {
  size_t n = 42;
  int (*p)[n] = foo(sizeof **p, n, n);
  if (!p) {
    return 1;
  }

  printf("p:");
  int accu = 0;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (size_t j = 0; j < sizeof *p / sizeof **p; j++) {
      p[i][j] = accu++;
      printf(" %d", p[i][j]);
    }
  }
  printf("\n");
  free(p);
}
```